# Create node programatically with nested fieldcollection item Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I need to create a node programmatically. In my content type there is a field collection in which there is another field collection. Now how can i save a value of a field in inner field collection So I am not able to save field collection item in this node because of this nested field collection structure.

Below is my code:

```
global $user;
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'key_sentence')); // replace entity_type and entity_bundle with your info
// Specify the author
$node->uid = $user->uid;
// Create a Entity Wrapper of that new Entity
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

// Specify the title
$entity->title = 'Test node';
// Add field data... SO MUCH BETTER!
$entity->field_key_sentence_text = 'Field value text';

$entity->save(); // necessary in order to attach field collections

//Outer field collection
$field_collection_1 = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_ks_sent_to'));
// Set default values as necessary
$field_collection_1->setHostEntity('field_collection_item', $entity); // again, replace entity_type as appropriate
$field_collection_1->save(TRUE);

//Inner field collection
$field_collection_2 = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_ks_in_voice'));
// Set default values as necessary
$field_collection_2->setHostEntity('field_collection_item', $field_collection_1);

//Field in inner field collection
$field_collection_2->field_message_url[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'http://www.google.com';
$field_collection_2->save(TRUE);

$entity->save();
```

But I am getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: value in field_collection_field_update() (line 933 of /home/postcinn/public_html/dev/sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.module).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type field_collection_item. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7766 of /home/postcinn/public_html/dev/includes/common.inc).
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Outer field collection
$field_collection_1 = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_ks_sent_to'));
// Set default values as necessary
$field_collection_1->setHostEntity('field_collection_item', $entity); // again, replace entity_type as appropriate
$field_collection_1->save(TRUE);
```

I'm thinking for starters you need to make sure your host entity for the first level of field collection is `node` type not `field_collection_item`.

Comment: I am not getting Dave what your are saying please make me understand. What is wrong and what should i do ?

Comment: Repeating code from the original question, and adding a sentence seems a poor way to answer.  Why not show what the code SHOULD look like.